# Username / password not specified Calling Amazon S3

Tags: c#, amazon-s3, webclient

We have been hitting a vendor provided file hosted on Amazon S3 for some time now, and noticed today our application is getting this message when attempting to download it

> Username / password not specified

We hit the file going through thier Site, but it tunnels into thier S3 account. It is Https with Basic Auth, so we tested it through a browser, with no issues. Here is the code we use to call it

```
  System.Uri responseUri = new System.Uri(DownloadFileLocation);
  WebClient client = new WebClient ();
  string authInfo = UserName + ":" + Password;
  authInfo = Convert.ToBase64String(Encoding.Default.GetBytes(authInfo));
  client.Headers["Authorization"] = "Basic " + authInfo;
  client.Headers.Add(HttpRequestHeader.UserAgent, "Mozilla/5.0 (Windows NT 6.1; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.1 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/21.0.1180.75 Safari/537.1");
  client.Headers.Add("Accept: text/html,application/zip,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,*/*;q=0.8");
  client.Headers.Add("Accept-Encoding: gzip,deflate,sdch");
  client.Headers.Add("Accept-Language: en-US,en;q=0.8");
  client.Headers.Add("Accept-Charset: ISO-8859-1,utf-8;q=0.7,*;q=0.3");
  client.DownloadFile(responseUri, LocalFilePath);
```

When the DownloadFile() method is called, we get the above error message, with no other indication of anything. I have looked around on Amazon Developer forums and haven't seen anything. Any help would be greatly appreciated, thanks

Comment: Consider using Amazon's API.

Comment: I agree with @SLaks. Is there any reason for not using Amazon's API?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Went through the vendor that fixed the basic auth on thier side

Answer (score 0):

Amazon S3 does not support Basic Auth so I suspect you are not actually hitting S3 directly but some intermediate layer that handles authentication. That is where you should be looking for the problem and a possible solution.

For information on the currently supported S3 authentication modes, check out:

http://s3.amazonaws.com/doc/s3-developer-guide/RESTAuthentication.html